# Версия Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Приветствую.

Я пока новичок в С\С++ . И в честь того чтоб копаться и изучать скачал "Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0" вроде аж 1998 года. Какие трудности могут возникнуть от старой версии? И может стоит начать с более новых (или старых :DDD ) версий студии?...Был бы не против если бы описали плюсы и минусы этой версии и более новых.

ps. Заранее Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложностей не много

- во первых, это очень старая версия. Но есть и ее почитатели
- во вторых, у этой версии свое видение стандарта.
- у нее специфический редактор, мне лично редактор от 2005 студии нравится больше.
- в четвертых, использование такой старой версии может несколько исказить мировосприятие

Comment: Ясна...А насчёт работа-способности и компилятора всё одно и тоже ?) ( извиняюсь если глупый вопрос...нуп совсем в нём :DDD )

Comment: в 98 году 6 студия - это было нормально. Сейчас - иногда школьник наваяет лучший интерфейс (не каждый конечно, но школьники разные бывают).
Но будьте готовы, что некоторые вещи будут нестандартно работать. Например, классический пример

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //....
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //....
    }
Не будет компилироватся, будет жаловатся, что переменная i объявлена дважды, тогда как современные компиляторы только так и примут.

Comment: Спасиба =)))

Answer (score 3):

Выбирайте `Visual Studio 2008 / 2010`.

Минусы `VC++6` по сравнению с новыми версиями `IDE` очевидны *(хотя в свое время она, как мне известно, была чрезвычайно популярна*):

- Неполная / неправильная поддержка стандарта `C++03` - особенно это касается шаблонов *(не говоря уже про стандарт `C++0x`)*.
- Менее удобные инструменты для отладки, хуже средства форматирования и анализа кода.
- Многие современные библиотеки *(`boost`, `Qt`)* не поддерживают 6 версию компилятора из-за первой причины и, соответственно, пользоваться ими нельзя.